# Runtime checking of Blocks and Queues in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have an array of dictionaries, that stores blocks and queues. After some method I need to execute it.

```
for (NSDictionary * dict in self.arrayOfBlocksAndQueues) {
    if (!dict[@"block"] || !dict[@"queue"]) {
        continue;
    }
    dispatch_block_t block = dict[@"block"];
    dispatch_async(dict[@"queue"], ^{
        block();
    });
}
```

So my question is, how can I check in runtime, that `dict[@"block"]` and `dict[@"queue"]` are exactly the type I’m expected? I have a `typedef void(^handler)();` and I need to be sure that `dict[@"block”]` is type of `handler`. As I know, blocks and queues are in fact objective-c objects, but don’t conforms to `<NSObject>` protocol. So, is there anyway to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with a block/queue property for easy manipulation. Try setting your block and queue properies with this class and add this objects in dictionary.

```
//Block class
@interface myBlock : NSObject

@property (assign) dispatch_block_t block;

@end

//Queue class
@interface myQueue : NSObject

@property (assign) dispatch_queue_t block;

@end
```